# Single-page website with one long background picture

Tags: fullpage.js

I`m wondering, is it possible to make single-page website with one long background picture on fullpage.js ? Because by default, you have to choose background for each section individually.
Example below: [single-page-long-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qti0l.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. Just apply the background the fullPage.js wrapper or the `body` and use a transparent one for each section.